# Display info icon inline in ion-item

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to display ionic info icon at the end of my input box. However, the following snippet shows only input box, not the icon:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>     
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <form  novalidate offset-lg-3 offset-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-xl-4>
    <ion-list inset>
      <p>Forget password</p>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input  placeholder="Email or Phone" name="email">
          </ion-input>
        <button ion-button clear >
          <ion-icon name="ios-information-circle-outline" ></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-item>    
    </ion-list>
    <button ion-button round full type="submit">Submit</button>    
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Current output:
[image]

expected output:
[image]

I would like to show some help text when the user clicks on the icon.I am certainly missing something here.What should I have done to make the icon appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ion-item` sets the content in a single row. You were missing an attribute `item-end` on the button. I would also recommend adding `icon-only` in order to get the full button as the specified icon.

Code:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <form  novalidate offset-lg-3 offset-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-xl-4>
    <ion-list inset>
      <p>Forget password</p>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input  placeholder="Email or Phone" name="email">
          </ion-input>
        <button ion-button clear item-end icon-only><!-- here -->
          <ion-icon name="ios-information-circle-outline" ></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-item>    
    </ion-list>
    <button ion-button round full type="submit">Submit</button>    
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-9p1xqy?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input  placeholder="Email or Phone" name="email">
      </ion-input>
    <button ion-button clear item-end icon-only>
    <ion-icon name="ios-information-circle-outline" ></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-item>
```

You have to use ion-icon inside ion-label

Comment: Ohh yes, I tried that the icon shows up on the left side and click event won't be available inside label.Will it be?

Comment: Do you need click event on Icon?

Comment: Misunderstand your question, now updated answer.
Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: No problem Thanks! However on top of Suraj's answer if I add click event on button then it submits the form which I don't want to happen.I just want to show alert.What could be done to prevent that submission?Will return false help?I think It should.Let me try.

Comment: add type="button" there all buttons are of type submit in html @Kumar

Comment: Remove (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" from  <form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()"> and add submitForm() to submit button on click.  
<button ion-button round full type="button" (click)="submitForm" >Submit</button>

Comment: Yes it did.Thanks Sagar.