# Ionic - button not showing up next to input

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to make a form. I need to have a label and under it - an input that has a button on the right side of it. This is the code:

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked class="config-view__input-label">Label text</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
      <button ion-button >
          <ion-icon name="md-add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
</ion-item>
```

The button just isnt showing up. What can I do to make this work?

If I add "item-right" to the button, it's not quite next to the input:
[image]

I wonder why when I try this the input and button just don't show up:

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked class="config-view__input-label">Label text</ion-label>
      <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
      <button ion-button >
          <ion-icon name="md-add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      </ion-item>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: did u import the css for ionic??? is it only at single place? does other icons work ?

Comment: how do you want it as?

Comment: It should be vertically centered relative to the input not the ion-item.

Comment: check the css in the browser.. especially the width of the elements

Comment: The input does not have 100% width.

Comment: cant do much without getting what you want to see...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display info icon inline in ion-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186864/display-info-icon-inline-in-ion-item)

Comment: Not a duplicate - this issue needs a different approach since there is an ion-item with a label and input and input has a stacked property. The approach in your mentioned question does not work for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `item-right` or `item-end` and `align-self: flex-end` to the `button`

```
<button item-end ion-button style="align-self: flex-end" >
      <ion-icon name="md-add"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: add `align-self: flex-end` to the css of the `button`

Comment: Mystery - that doesn't help as the button takes up the whole height of the ion-item. Also kind of hacky.

Comment: This is what it looks like in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xtdaxh?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html) Please check maybe something affects your button styling.

Comment: I apologize - I did have another style class affecting that. You have the correct answer to this question - just add this bit about align-self: flex-end to your answer. ;)